# How to plot the chart with customized point order in django-chartit?

Tags: python, django, highcharts

In my application, I have such string value (which is known as version id for a specific application) for x-axis: `1.1, 1.2, 1.11...`.

The default order of points showing in the chart generated by `django-chartit` and `highcharts` is based on lexicographical order such that the x-axis values are displayed in the order
  `1.1, 1.11, 1.2`.

How can I customize the plotting order such that they will be shown in the order 
  `1.1, 1.2, 1.11...` ?

By the way, i have tried several unsuccessful ways to solve this problem, and I find the order of the data `source` specified in the django backend has nothing to do with the order of that shown in the chart in the front-end. Thus solutions directly working on `Highcharts` may work.

Any ideas will be welcomed.

Comment: What is the difference between django-chartit and highcharts? Which one is generating the actual plotting?

Comment: @AbijithMg `django-chartit` is an application such that we can generate the highchart chart-config such as title, series data source in the django-backend, which is a kind of  encapsulation. However, the data still needs to be parsed as JSON and passed to highchart() method in the front-end to plot the target chart.